# Create OpenGL context in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm currently developing an OpenGL application and I want to use Qt for the other stuff. I want to use OpenGL like I use it with GLFW and without Qt functions. Just normal OpenGL. I cant find any site which uses Qt like id like to. So I only want to use Qt for the Windows and creating context and so on, but use OpenGL for the rest.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

There is an old-school [QOpenGLWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) that will create an OpenGL context. That will give a window with an area to draw on.

Other option is the [Scene Graph - OpenGL Under QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html) - pretty much the same, but it also allows to have QML user interface (buttons, edits, etc.) above your OpenGL rendering.